# Use $_REQUEST within a URL string when using cURL?

Tags: php, curl

I am able to successfully use the something like this $_REQUEST on my page when its loaded in PHP:

```
<?php echo $_REQUEST['topicname']; ?>
```

However, when I then try to use that "topicname" on the same page to grab a webpage via cURL it fails and gets me this error:

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ''
>   (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or
>   variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)

This is the way I am trying to implement the code when it throws that error:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.domain.net/reports/?search=. $_REQUEST['topicname'] .");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Ideas on what should be altered? Thank you

Comment: `"https://www.domain.net/reports/?search=".$_REQUEST['topicname']);`

Comment: Your quotes aren't balanced. Doesn't your IDE warn you about stuff like this?

Comment: I use TextEdit ;). Solved with adding {}

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.domain.net/reports/?search=". $_REQUEST['topicname'] );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
?>
```